# Calendar API sometimes returns NULL Event Attendees

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

Has anybody come across an issue with the V3 Calendar API where sometimes the Attendee data is returned empty even though there are valid attendees on an Event?

The Events always have valid attendees.

An Event Get returns Attendees = NULL

Here is a code snippet of an Event Query

```
            calendarToolsV3 cv3 = new calendarToolsV3(true, calendar, int.Parse(organisationId));
            EventsResource.GetRequest gr = new EventsResource.GetRequest(cv3.service, calendar, eventId);
            gr.AlwaysIncludeEmail = true;
            Event evv = gr.Execute();

            litDiagnosis.Text = "Summary | " + evv.Summary + "<br/>";
            litDiagnosis.Text += "Id | " + evv.Id + "<br/>";
            litDiagnosis.Text += "RecurringEventId | " + evv.RecurringEventId + "<br/>";
            litDiagnosis.Text += "Status | " + evv.Status + "<br/>";
            litDiagnosis.Text += "Visibility | " + evv.Visibility + "<br/>";
            litDiagnosis.Text += "Start | " + (evv.Start == null ? evv.Start.Date.ToString() : evv.Start.DateTime.ToString() + "<br/>");
            if (evv.Attendees != null && evv.Attendees.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (EventAttendee ea in evv.Attendees)
                {
                    litDiagnosis.Text += "Attendee | " + ea.Email + "|" + ea.ResponseStatus + "<br/>";
                }
            }
```

****** EDIT **************

I have done some further testing and it seems that this occurs where the original APPT is a recurring APPT.

The user that I am interrogating the Event with has declined the Event

The attendees are no longer visible to that user.

The attendees are however visible to the Creator of the Event.  When the Event is deleted the Attendees become visible again to that user?

When the Event is not Recurring this behaviour is not observed and all users can view all Attendees even when declined/deleted?

*********************** EXAMPLE CAPTURE FROM API EXPLORER ***************

**Event Created by admin@i3000.co.  Attendee Lisa.Jones@i3000.co queries the Event and can see the Attendess**

```
{
 "kind": "calendar#event",
 "etag": "\"2869345662384000\"",
 "id": "7d3pmni42o6pg6taeudsskhfh8",
 "status": "confirmed",
 "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=N2QzcG1uaTQybzZwZzZ0YWV1ZHNza2hmaDhfMjAxNTA2MTlUMjIwMDAwWiBsaXNhLmpvbmVzQGkzMDAwLmNv",
 "created": "2015-06-19T00:13:22.000Z",
 "updated": "2015-06-19T00:13:51.192Z",
 "summary": "ATTENDEE TEST",
 "colorId": "11",
 "creator": {
  "email": "admin@i3000.co",
  "displayName": "Admin User"
 },
 "organizer": {
  "email": "admin@i3000.co",
  "displayName": "Admin User"
 },
 "start": {
  "dateTime": "2015-06-20T08:00:00+10:00",
  "timeZone": "America/New_York"
 },
 "end": {
  "dateTime": "2015-06-20T09:00:00+10:00",
  "timeZone": "America/New_York"
 },
 "recurrence": [
  "RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;COUNT=2;BYDAY=FR"
 ],
 "iCalUID": "7d3pmni42o6pg6taeudsskhfh8@google.com",
 "sequence": 0,
 "attendees": [
  {
   "email": "admin@i3000.co",
   "displayName": "Admin User",
   "organizer": true,
   "responseStatus": "accepted"
  },
  {
   "email": "lisa.jones@i3000.co",
   "displayName": "lisa jones",
   "self": true,
   "responseStatus": "needsAction"
  }
 ],
 "extendedProperties": {
  "private": {
   "ilink": "recur7d3pmni42o6pg6taeudsskhfh8"
  }
 },
 "hangoutLink": "https://plus.google.com/hangouts/_/i3000.co/admin-lisa-jone?hceid=YWRtaW5AaTMwMDAuY28.7d3pmni42o6pg6taeudsskhfh8",
 "reminders": {
  "useDefault": true
 }
}
```

**Lisa.Jones Removes the Event from her Calendar and Queries again - Attendees are not Visible**

```
{

 "kind": "calendar#event",
 "etag": "\"2869346050176000\"",
 "id": "7d3pmni42o6pg6taeudsskhfh8",
 "status": "cancelled",
 "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=N2QzcG1uaTQybzZwZzZ0YWV1ZHNza2hmaDhfMjAxNTA2MTlUMjIwMDAwWiBsaXNhLmpvbmVzQGkzMDAwLmNv",
 "created": "2015-06-19T00:13:22.000Z",
 "updated": "2015-06-19T00:17:05.088Z",
 "summary": "ATTENDEE TEST",
 "colorId": "11",
 "creator": {
  "email": "admin@i3000.co",
  "displayName": "Admin User"
 },
 "organizer": {
  "email": "admin@i3000.co",
  "displayName": "Admin User"
 },
 "start": {
  "dateTime": "2015-06-20T08:00:00+10:00",
  "timeZone": "America/New_York"
 },
 "end": {
  "dateTime": "2015-06-20T09:00:00+10:00",
  "timeZone": "America/New_York"
 },
 "recurrence": [
  "RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;COUNT=2;BYDAY=FR"
 ],
 "iCalUID": "7d3pmni42o6pg6taeudsskhfh8@google.com",
 "sequence": 0,
 "extendedProperties": {
  "private": {
   "ilink": "recur7d3pmni42o6pg6taeudsskhfh8"
  }
 },
 "hangoutLink": "https://plus.google.com/hangouts/_/i3000.co/admin-lisa-jone?hceid=YWRtaW5AaTMwMDAuY28.7d3pmni42o6pg6taeudsskhfh8",
 "reminders": {
  "useDefault": true
 }
}
```

**Admin@i3000.co now deletes the Event.  When Lisa.Jones Queries the Event the Attendees are again visible**

```
{

 "kind": "calendar#event",
 "etag": "\"2869346122438000\"",
 "id": "7d3pmni42o6pg6taeudsskhfh8",
 "status": "cancelled",
 "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=N2QzcG1uaTQybzZwZzZ0YWV1ZHNza2hmaDhfMjAxNTA2MTlUMjIwMDAwWiBsaXNhLmpvbmVzQGkzMDAwLmNv",
 "created": "2015-06-19T00:13:22.000Z",
 "updated": "2015-06-19T00:17:41.219Z",
 "summary": "ATTENDEE TEST",
 "colorId": "11",
 "creator": {
  "email": "admin@i3000.co",
  "displayName": "Admin User"
 },
 "organizer": {
  "email": "admin@i3000.co",
  "displayName": "Admin User"
 },
 "start": {
  "dateTime": "2015-06-20T08:00:00+10:00",
  "timeZone": "America/New_York"
 },
 "end": {
  "dateTime": "2015-06-20T09:00:00+10:00",
  "timeZone": "America/New_York"
 },
 "recurrence": [
  "RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;COUNT=2;BYDAY=FR"
 ],
 "iCalUID": "7d3pmni42o6pg6taeudsskhfh8@google.com",
 "sequence": 1,
 "attendees": [
  {
   "email": "lisa.jones@i3000.co",
   "displayName": "lisa jones",
   "self": true,
   "responseStatus": "needsAction"
  },
  {
   "email": "admin@i3000.co",
   "displayName": "Admin User",
   "organizer": true,
   "responseStatus": "accepted"
  }
 ],
 "extendedProperties": {
  "private": {
   "ilink": "recur7d3pmni42o6pg6taeudsskhfh8"
  }
 },
 "hangoutLink": "https://plus.google.com/hangouts/_/i3000.co/admin-lisa-jone?hceid=YWRtaW5AaTMwMDAuY28.7d3pmni42o6pg6taeudsskhfh8",
 "reminders": {
  "useDefault": true
 }
}
```

Comment: I tried the above scenario, by creating recurring event with user1, user2 and I am the creator of the event. Both user1 and user2 are other accounts(which I am not owned). Recurring event is accepted by user2 and declined by user1. But user1 is still able to see user2 in the attendees list. Try in API explorer https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/get

Comment: I have updated my question with an example from the API Explorer.  Also noted that Attendees are made visible once the Creator Deletes the Event.

Comment: The status of the event after Lisa removed it is "cancelled". Do you need attendees on deleted events?

Comment: We use the API to synchronise with an external calendar - so we need to see the attendees.  When synchronising if the Event is "cancelled" then we delete from the external calendar - however if there is another valid attendee on the Event then we shouldn't delete.  Also the attendees are visible to Lisa once it is deleted by Admin - so this is not consistent behaviour?